# Should I update/change my answer or submit a new answer to a question?

Tags: discussion, answers

I would like to submit a different answer to this question: [How can I force Ubuntu 22.04 SERVER to use ONLY the DNS servers listed in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf (NOT my router's DNS) AND use DNS-over-TLS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464051/how-can-i-force-ubuntu-22-04-server-to-use-only-the-dns-servers-listed-in-etc-s)

My new answer is significantly different than what I previously submitted. Futhermore, there are several comments to my original answer that would no longer apply if I replaced.

These are the options I see:

- Replace the original
- Update and add to the original
- Submit a new answer

What is the best protocol?

Comment: Is the old answer wrong or invalid somehow?

Comment: (Also, don't worry too much about comments. They're not meant to stick around - any truly important information should be added to the post as the comments can be, and often are, deleted any time for any or no reason.)

Comment: @muru It's not that the original answer is wrong or invalid. After doing more research and thinking about the OP's initial question/problem, I've concluded that there's a better way to solve the issue. It not only solves the problem but is more flexible in the long run. And in some ways, it's probably "more correct." Also, I feel that it's more in line with how the underlying design of systemd-resolved was intended to be used with regards to Split DNS, routing domains, and search domains. So my original answer is like putting a band-aid on the problem instead of actually addressing it.

Comment: Ah, then it's fine, you can and probably should post a new answer. You can edit your current answer to suggest the other one is preferred.

Comment: @muru Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's fine to add a new answer. It's unusual, but it can be the right thing to do in a situation where:

- You have a new idea that's distinct from the idea you expressed in your existing answer (so it doesn't feel right to just extend or update your existing answer, especially if people have already voted and commented on it)
- Your existing answer isn't wrong (so it doesn't feel right to correct or delete your existing answer)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @mpboden thanks for asking :)